# Where are all the properties in my Visual Studio Installer Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, windows-installer

In Visual Studio Installer Project, there are placeholders\macros properties like `[ProgramFilesFolder]` and `[ProductName]`. Where can I see all these properties and their values ? I downloaded Orca, but I can't figure that info from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is [the list of all WI properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905.aspx) with explanations.

Comment: @Yan: that's great. When I add a file to the MSI, does it get a property that I can use (so I won't have to worry when changing its destination-name in the MSI package, to change all references to it within the MSI) ?

Comment: You can use TARGETDIR property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372064(v=vs.85).aspx